# How to integrate or send files upto 2GB to SharePoint

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, integration, callout, sharepoint

We need to send files from Salesforce to Sharepoint with upto 2GB of a single file size. We are aware of Salesforce governor limits of Salesforce/Apex where it cannot process asynchronous API calls of more than 12MB and because of which we cannot send these big files from Apex API calls to Sharepoint Sites.

We are able to send files of upto 250MB to Sharepoint via Sharepoint API from Javascript component in LWC and not involving Apex in the API calls,

But the Sharepoint document also suggest that it can accept upto 2GB files in the API. Any suggetions on how these 2GB single file can be uploaded from Salesforce (LWC or Apex) to Sharepoint.

Below is the code for 250MB from Salesforce to Sharepoint via LWC:-

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Upload" icon-name="custom:custom14">
            <lightning-input type="File" label="file uploader" name="file uploader" onchange={handleFileLOad}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
</template>

=======================================================================================================================================================================

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SharePointApiIntegration extends LightningElement {
  accesstoken = 'aaaxxxxxxx';
  filesUploaded = [];
  fileName;
  typeFile;

  handleFileLOad(event) {
    console.log('1111111');
    this.filesUploaded = event.target.files;
    this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
    console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.filesUploaded));
    console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.fileName));
    this.typeFile = event.target.files[0].type;
    console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.typeFile));
  }

    handleClick(event) {
      console.log('Enter');
      console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.filesUploaded));
    console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.fileName));
    console.log('nameFile'+JSON.stringify(this.typeFile));
    

      var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("title", this.fileName);
        formData.append("type", this.typeFile);
        formData.append("image", this.filesUploaded[0]);
        console.log('Size of data'+JSON.stringify(formData));
        const endpoint = 'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSitepos/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'' + '/sites/TestSitepos/Shared%20Documents/Test' + '\')/Files/add(url=\'' + this.fileName + '\',overwrite=true)';
        console.log(this.accesstoken);
        fetch(endpoint, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.accesstoken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=nometadata'
         },
          body: formData
        })
      .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Response'+JSON.stringify(data));
          alert('File uploaded successfully!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error'+JSON.stringify(error));
          alert('Error uploading file');
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use chunk API to upload such a large files. Basically you need to create upload session. Here are some examles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165695/upload-large-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-microsoft-graph-via-rest-api

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/programmatically-uploading-large-files-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.